# I have lots of lock icons -- how can I get rid of them?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

The top bar of my screen looks like this:

[image: Too many lock icons]

What's with all the locks? Can I get rid of some of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon is for Keychain Access. You can enable and disable the icon (usually there's only one) from the Keychain Access app's preferences. Try toggling this checkbox and seeing what happens.

Multiple icons is sometimes a rare glitch where other menu bar items appear with the wrong icon, taking on the appearance of a different item. This can usually be fixed by killing SystemUIServer (`killall -HUP SystemUIServer`).

If it really is multiple menu bar items, you can remove them by ⌘-dragging them away from the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks. Using Keychain Access and toggling the checkbox off would remove one of them, then by repeatedly opening the preferences I could turn them off one by one. I'm going to try restarting and see if the change holds.

Comment: After reboot I still have only the one icon. Thanks again.